# Is there a card that lets me draw whenever a card is put in an opponent's graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a mill deck that uses [Sphinx's Tutelage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398520) among other things. I'd like to find a card that could combo with it by allowing me to draw when a card is put in an opponent's graveyard. I'm not sure such a card exists.

[Compost](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15881) would be perfect, except it only works with black cards. There should also be a way to get out of the loop so I don't mill myself.

Modern-legal would be best but this is more about curiosity so it's not super important.

Comment: Doing some searches on gatherer only leads me to Compost.  Anything else that I could find that triggers off of cards going to the graveyard like that caused life loss (usually), not card draw.

Comment: That's what I figured but my gatherer-fu isn't the best. I might just sideboard Compost for maximum trolling against black heavy decks.

Comment: Pretty sure no, or Jace's Erasure would already be a combo. The normal mill combos (in modern) are Mindcrank + Bloodchief Ascension/Duskmantle Guildmage.

Comment: There are no two-card or even three-card infinite combos with Sphinx's tutelage. Closest I can think of would be Sphinx's Tutelage, Undead Alchemist, and Beck (of Beck // Call), but even that's not guaranteed. It requires them to have more than 50% of their deck be creatures, and even still can whiff.

Comment: "No there isn't" is a perfectly valid answer. You guys should post it as such so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add [Painter's Servant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=146022) to your combo of Sphinx's Tutelage and Compost.

With Painter's Servant in play, every card your opponent mills will be Black and cause a Compost trigger.  So as soon as the Sphinx's Tutelage trigger first resolves, your opponent will mill (at least) 2, netting you two more draw triggers, causing 2 more sphinx triggers, leading to 4 more draw triggers causing 4 more sphinx triggers leading to 8 more draw triggers, etc etc.

Compost is a 'may' so you don't need to worry about milling yourself if you want to stop.

Comment: This answer would be better with a brief explanation of what the combo does.

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that this is not modern-legal because Compost is too old, and in Legacy, it's simpler to just play Painter's Servant/Grindstone.

Comment: Actually compost is unnecessary; with painters servant in play all the opponents cards will share a color, the color named. This will cause the mill effect to repeat until there are no cards left!

Comment: @esoterik Sphinx's Tutelage specifies that the cards have to be nonland, so Compost still has an effect there. As murgatroid mentoined, though, Grindstone works by itself with Painter's Servant (it doesn't say "nonland").

Comment: A clause one imagines was added to the card specifically to *prevent* a painter+grindstone type combo in modern!

Comment: This seems to be the best answer (along with the comments) since Anthony stated any card combos as a matter of curiosity, i.e. kitchen table win an easy bet with your friend play.

Comment: Is there anything like Painter's Servant that is legal in commander?

Comment: One speculates that if another card had the same effect as Painter's Servant it would also be banned in Commander for all the same reasons....!

Answer (score 2):

To post as an answer what was hashed out in the comments, there is no card that will do what you want at this time.  Any available cards have restrictions (like Compost) or result in other things like life loss.